# C++ unnamed typed struct member

Tags: c++

First, I'll start with what does work:

```cpp
struct A
{
    int a, b;
};

struct S
{
    A A_;// Member can be defined elsewhere.
    struct B
    {
        int c, d;
    };// Member can be defined locally.
    B B_;
    struct C
    {
        int e, f;
    } C_;// Member can be instanced on the same line...
    C C2_;// ...and the definition still works.
    struct
    {
        int g, h;
    } D_;// Member can be defined without a type name and be named.
    // (and obiously there is no way to make an instance afterwards)
    struct
    {
        int i, j;
    };// Member can be defined without a type name and be unnamed.
    // (and obiously there is no way to make an instance afterwards)
};
```

Members of an unnamed struct (and untyped) can be accessed in the code directly (that is a non-standard extension):

```cpp
int main()
{
    S s;
    s.i;
    s.j;
}
```

Is there any way to create a similar scenario but with an unnamed but typed member?

```cpp
struct X
{
    struct Y
    {
        int k, l;
    };
};

int main()
{
    X x;
    x.k;
    x.l;
}
```

Obviously the code above is incorrect as the `struct Y{...}` is interpreted as a local struct definition.

Comment: maybe using inheritance? `struct X : public Y {};`

Comment: In your last example, `X` doesn't in fact have members named `k` or `l`. It also doesn't have a data member of type `Y`. It has no data members at all, of any name.

Comment: @WeiHsieh I was about to write an angry comment like "obviously not because multiple inheritance", and then realised "obviously yes because multiple inheritance"... Thanks!

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Yes, in fact, if you look closely, you can see that i addressed that.

Comment: @WeiHsieh However this is not quite what i am looking for: this solution also allows everything that inheritance allows (e.g. upcasts). Also there is no way to fit some elements inbetween: ``struct K : public L, int, M {...};``, or do unions that include the base classes.

Comment: "Members of an unnamed struct (and untyped) can be accessed in the code directly" - that is a non-standard extension.

Comment: @Eugene It is standard enough... Even though it is not in the specs, it works on every(?) popular compiler.

Comment: There is no such thing as "standard enough". "Standard" means complying with one of the C++ standards. "works on every(?) popular compiler" is an extension.

Comment: @Eugene Am I going to ship this code? As a source? No? Then I don't care.

Comment: @beothunder actually it can, you just need to define it inside of a struct. like `struct Int{int  i;};`. To disable upcast, you can private inherit the classes and bring the fields public via `using declaration`. ofcourse it's just a mimic. I don't think there's a compiler support what you want.

Comment: Non-standard does not mean wrong. You may not care indeed. I just wanted other readers of this site to know.

Comment: @WeiHsieh Yes, there isn't. What I wanted leads to ambiguities, I am writing the answer now. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now that I thought about it, I can see that what I want is impossible.

If something like this is allowed then it creates ambiguities in the case of

```cpp
struct X
{
    int k, l;
};

struct Y
{
    X;// unnamed (X1)
    X;// unnamed (X2)
};
```

The near miss solutions are:

- Inheritance

```cpp
struct Y : X {...};
```

First of all, along with what I want, this allows all the bells and whistles of inheritance (for example upcasts) which was not the intention. Second, this only allows limited memory management: there is no way to insert any values before the base, or between multiple bases (at least without creating dummy structs, that then can also be upcasted to), or use unions in fancy ways. And again you can't inherit the same type twice (which is so obvious that this is actually how i got to this inconsistancy conclusion).

- Hardcoded

```cpp
struct Y
{
    union
    {
        X X_;
        struct
        {
            int k, l;
        };
    };
};
```

This one is just ugly and not "robust". At this point it would be actually better to abandon this scheme alltogether.

- Private inheritance with usings

```cpp
struct Y : private X
{
    using X::k;
    using X::l;
};
```

This solution prevents unwanted upcasts, but it is basically just as messy as the hardcoded one (though at least it does not allow to use a non existing member).